# How are the "lucky JPL peanuts" shared post-pandemic?

Tags: nasa, safety, health, mission-control, jpl

The extremely cool NASA JPL video *[Triumph at Saturn (Part I)](https://youtu.be/SY-hQJ5pMd4?t=2219)* is really worth a watch and/or listen. (Don't forget Part II as well!)

A bit after `36:59` it discusses the "lucky JPL peanuts" tradition:

> A JPL Tradition has begun, starting in the back of the Mission Support area. This is the consuming of the Lucky JPL Peanuts.

**Question:** How are the "lucky JPL peanuts" shared post-pandemic?

Presumably the tradition would not be dropped, yet the sharing food in close proximity and passing it down the line would not be consistent with strict COVID prevention guidelines. Would each individual now bring their own peanuts? Or does one person carefully split up "peanut doses" from a bottle and distribute them? Something else?

---

[image: Sharing the lucky JPL peanuts from "Triumph at Saturn (Part I)"]

[image: Sharing the lucky JPL peanuts from "Triumph at Saturn (Part I)"]

Answer (score 18):

People received individual packages of peanuts and could sneak one under their mask.

[This page](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/news/10022/what-are-jpls-lucky-peanuts/) shows people holding individual packages of peanuts.

[image]

And [this video](https://youtu.be/ajH5LUyCUA8?t=56) explains the procedure briefly.